# Fullcalendar 6.1.0 : StartTime and EndTime are changing when date is changed

Tags: datetime, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

if i change the eventDate from a certain date, the startTime and end endTime is changing by one our!

```
{
    "allDay" : false,
    "end" : "2023-03-25T10:30:00.000Z",
    "focus" : "2023-03-22T23:00:00.000Z",
    "id" : "F290E99B-B8C4-49FE-AED5-36078EB60C34",
    "start" : "2023-03-25T09:30:00.000Z"
}

{
    "allDay" : false,
    "end" : "2023-03-26T09:30:00.000Z",
    "focus" : "2023-03-22T23:00:00.000Z",
    "id" : "F290E99B-B8C4-49FE-AED5-36078EB60C34",
    "start" : "2023-03-26T08:30:00.000Z"
}
```

This only occurs when i change the date from 2023-03-26 on or later.
If the date is earlier, the time is correct.
Thank you for the help
Juergen

Occurs on any events.

Comment: I found out, it is a daylight savings problem.

Comment: I have my System and Fullcalendar set to local timezone. But i don´t understand why Fullcalendar ist showing the event in the calendar with the correct time (same time on 03-25 and 03-26) but when click on the event at date 26-3 it parses the time one hour earlier.

Comment: It sounds like it might be an internal bug in fullCalendar. If you can reliably reproduce it in the latest version, you can submit a [bug report](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs). Here at Stackoverflow we can help you with configuring your calendar, and with bugs in your own implementation code, but we cannot help much with internal issues in the library. If the same event is being displayed different in two different calendar views, then that probably sounds like an internal issue (although I cannot be 100% sure since you didn't provide a [mre] here for us to look at).

Comment: https://codepen.io/JSeee/pen/PodwyjN?editors=0010 (TestCase on codepen)

Comment: Thanks. What exactly are the steps to reproduce the problem? Because looking at the demo, I can't see any problem (but it's possible that might be because my timezone is the same as UTC anyway)

Comment: Summertime this year is from 26.03.2023. Change the event to 25.03 and click on it, time is: Start: 2023-03-25T09:30:00.000ZEnd: 2023-03-25T10:30:00.000Z. Then drag an drop the event to 26.03 time is: Start: 2023-03-26T08:30:00.000ZEnd: 2023-03-26T09:30:00.000Z. On the Calendardisplay the time is not changing.

Comment: I see. Well in that case I'd say the time shouldn't change on the display, because the calendar is set to display in the local timezone, and your event is defined as being in UTC. So when you move it to a date which is in a different timezone (due to daylight savings), it tries to preserve the local time of the event, and so changes the UTC time accordingly. If you were to use the timeGrid view to drag the event (even to a different time of day on the new date) you'd see it more clearly. I'd say that's probably the expected behaviour, but you can query it with the fullCalendar team if you wish

Comment: There is some more background information available in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-object, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Thank you, i was confused, that the calendar display ist not corresponding to the underlaying event data. I think i´m going UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The time shouldn't change on the display, because the calendar is set to display in the local timezone, and your event is defined as being in UTC.

So when you move it to a date which is in a different timezone (due to daylight savings), you are setting it to the local time of the event, and so in the background fullCalendar changes the UTC time of the event accordingly.

If you were to use the timeGrid view to drag the event (even to a different time of day on the new date) you can see the effect more clearly.